# Spam on the blog site?

Tags: support, spam, blog

There's a load of spam on the blog right now. How do I report it?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's no longer possible to comment on blog posts, so they can't be spammed.

Answer (score 11):

To report spam on the blog:

1. email team@stackexchange.com (aka the "contact us" link at the bottom of every page)
2. please include the URL of the blog entry with the spam in your email

And thank you!

Comment: AHHH! A ghost!!

Comment: And an alternate route which works for security.blogoverflow.com is to tell the mods in the security chat room.

Answer (score 4):

There should be a requirement to log in with a Stack Exchange account, and/or add flag buttons  next to the posts. Or run the comments through Akismet.

Comment: Comments do go through Akismet, but it is not perfect.