# Spam on blog.stackoverflow.com

Tags: support, spam, blog

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Spam on the blog site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/46198/spam-on-the-blog-site)

There are [spam comments on many of the blog posts](http://www.google.de/search?q=site%3Ablog.stackoverflow.com+boots). These should probably be removed.

(There also might be more than those found by that simple google search).

Comment: Time to trim the digital back yard.

Comment: @voyager You mean to weed it?

Comment: Those guys again.  I keep wondering why they think it's effective to target this community with ads for those products.  It just doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Bill: you are assuming they are thinking...