# Is there any way to report spam in BlogOverflow comments?

Tags: support, spam, blog

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Spam on the blog site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/46198/spam-on-the-blog-site)

For example, there's a [spam comment](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/12/the-best-of-blog-overflow-november-2011/#comment-67019) on the StackOverflow blog.

Comment: But then where will you get your custom jerseys???

Comment: Another one: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/11/the-best-of-blog-overflow-october-2011/#comment-65488

Comment: Well, looks like Jeff [personally cleaned](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/46198/2) spam comments when previously reported on Meta..

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd It's a semi-duplicate, but the old one doesn't really have a useful answer, I think the old one should be closed as a duplicate of this one.

Comment: @Yannis I found other post closed as duplicate of the one I posted - guess it doesn't really matter.

Comment: @YannisRizos. The old one has an answer now. From Jeff Atwood, no less.

Comment: @TRiG I noticed. Still don't care much for the old one though, I don't want the canonical question to be the penis enlargement one (edited out, but I _know_ it's there ;)

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. I deleted it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no flagging system for blog comments (that I know of), but you could always send an email to `team@stackoverflow.com`.

Answer (score 6):

Other than [emailing the team](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/137654/162704), you can drop in the [Assembly](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2691/the-assembly), a chat room that's usually full of moderators. Even if no one's around, just post the link to the blog post, write SPAM!!!, and we'll take care of it, by quickly forwarding it to the team - if one of them isn't in the Assembly already.

Comment: This is very useful information :)