# No 'Mark Spam' Button on Blog Comments?

Tags: feature-request, comments, spam, blog

I was on the Stack Overflow Blog and came across a [spam comment](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/11/announcing-bosun-our-new-open-source-monitoring-alerting-system/#comment-96947). I thought let me just mark it as spam. But, hmm, where's the spam button? Came here, was writing the title and saw the [original question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137653/is-there-any-way-to-report-spam-in-blogoverflow-comments) about it. *But, do you expect a user to send an email everytime they see a spam? Seriously?*

Why not add a 'flag' button instead?

Comment: Fastest way would be drawing attention of a dev/CM in chat, or emailing them the link.

Comment: that one's unanswered. but anyways thanks for bringing it to my attention.

Comment: So? Just because the first one is not yet answered doesn't mean it's not duplicate. If you care enough about something, you can start a bounty to bump it. (that said, no need to delete this)

Comment: Well, the same question again, do you really expect a user to do one of those things everytime?

Comment: If there will be too much spam I guess they will re-think the decision. As it stands, I don't think it's a big enough problem to justify spending time and money on developing a flagging mechanism for blogs.